# what is uses-permission "android.permission.INTERNET"?

Tags: applications, permissions

I read something about uses-permission in android application , but I don't know what is "android.permission.INTERNET" , or why we need this.

Comment: Is this a development question? Those are off-topic here.

Comment: not at all , I need what is , I know this is in AndroidManifest.xml but many time use 10.x.x.x I don't know how to get that?

Comment: You can find a list of permissions with explanations [here](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=perms#INTERNET) on my Android site, which goes beyond the question linked above. The link in this comment goes directly to the permission you've asked for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### android.permission.INTERNET is a permission required by apps that access the Internet in any capacity.

Many applications use this permission to get data from a remote server, display advertisements, or send usage statistics to the developer.

If you're wondering why a specific app requires the permission, your best bet would be to ask the developer directly.